# ODBC 18 vs ODBC 17 in Windows Data Source Manager

Tags: odbc

I have a microsoft access front end connecting to a SQL database for the backend.  I have been using this setup for the last 4 years and I have recently run into issues with new associates not being able to use the tool due to our company retiring ODBC driver 17 from our internal systems.  I don't understand what is the difference between ODBC Driver 17 and 18 that would cause version 18 to fail.

How the driver is used:
in ODBC Data source manager a manual link to our database is created.  The associate enters a specific name for the link "Our_link" and in the Driver name it states "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"

Then inside of our access front end we link to that driver like so:

```
Const ConStrSQL As String = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQLServer};Server=OurServer;Database=Our_DB;UID=User();Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
```

The issue I am having is when I try to create the ODBC connection in the data source administrator using ODBC driver 18 I get an error that states:

```
 [![`"Connection Failed: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted"`]
```

Not sure if this extra information would help but I also see the following:

```
SQLState: 08001

SQL Server Error -2146893019

Client unable to establish connection
```

Is this something I need to reach out to our database admin group and ask if they installed driver 18 on the server side?

[image: ODBC Manager]
[image: Authority Not Trusted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'fix' that was found with the help of one of my database admins is as follows:

In the data source manager there is an option to select that states "Trust Server Certificate"

Once that option is selected I was able to complete the rest of my DSM connection.  One thing to note is I was receiving the previous error when trying to change the DEFAULT DATABASE option.  The checkbox to "trust server certificate" is on the screen after that.. so I had to skip choosing my default database, check the box, then go back and select my default database for everything to work.

I haven't completed all my testing in Access to make sure everything works 100%, but my quick testing is very promising.

[image: Change Default Database]
[image: Trust Server Connection]

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution is to add `;TrustServerCertificate=Yes` to the connection string

Comment: hmm.. Not sure how/why this wasn't offered in a solution from my DB admins.. or if they knew/are allowed to recommend this type of answer.. Definitely a more sleek answer that requires less of new associates to get it working.  I'll be implementing this in our next version update for sure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it has to do with the changes to the encryption behavior with version 18, specifically that encryption is required by default. The recommended fix is to install a trusted certificate on your server[1], but if you don't want to deal with the DB Admins you might be able to still connect by specifying No (or optional) to **Encrypt** in your connection string.[2]

There is a chance that won't work the server is set to Force Encryption, but it sounds like the change is all on the client end. Ideally you would want the encryption working all the time, so if you are using a self-signed certificate add the public key from the SQL server to trusted certificates on the client machines.

[1]: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228)
[2]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/dsn-connection-string-attribute?view=sql-server-ver16#encrypt

Comment: Not sure exactly how it all fits together.. but the 'fix' ended up being an option inside the DSM itself.. a little checkbox needs to be ticked stating 'trust server certificate'.. I never noticed the checkbox before (never needed it) and that option shows up on a screen AFTER I was receiving the error.  I had to skip the screen I was getting the error, check the box, then go back to the previous screen to enter my specific default database.  Kind of a pain to figure out, but we got it figured out.